# Using Blockwise Inversion on a $5 \times 5$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

My question could be considered more general than the $5 \times 5$ case, but I'm wondering how when using Blockwise inversion you can select an appropriate $\bf A$, $\bf C$, and $\bf B$ such that the matrix sizes confirm for multiplication of $\textbf{D} - \textbf{C}\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}$

For example,

- $\bf A$ is $2 \times 2$
- $\bf B$ is $2 \times 3$
- $\bf C$ is $3 \times 2$
- $\bf D$ is $3 \times 3$

Lead to $\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}$ being a $2 \times 3$ matrix which is improper for multiplication by a $3 \times 3$.

Trying $\bf A$ being $3 \times 3$ seemed to lead to the same issue, am I missing something?

Comment: No it should be OK. $(3 x 2) (2x2) (2x3)$. The internal dimensions must agree and they will do pairwise no matter which order you do the multiplication (2=2 and 2=2). You end up with $3x3$. ($\bf C$ is according to your list not a 3x3 but it will be a $3x2$ multiplied with $2x3$ which gives a $3x3$)

Comment: Schur's complement associated with a $2 \times 2$ partition with square diagonal blocks $\textbf{D} - \textbf{C}\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}$ (it is its name) is always well defined.

Comment: We will need to make sure that any block which is non-square does not have any inverse occuring in the formula as it will be impossible to construct a lossless inverse for any non-square matrix. For example if you had chosen $\bf A$ to be $2x3$ you would have trouble finding ${\bf A}^{-1}$. Except for that all the size-considerations should be compatible no matter which partition you make.